# zendframework 2 form populating MultiCheckbox values from a database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am using zendframework 2 and doctrine 2. i want to populate the values of my MultiCheckbox from values in my database .
i got the technique from: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md

```
namespace Users\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
class addForm extends form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
protected $objectManager;
public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
}

public function getObjectManager()
{
    return $this->objectManager;
}
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('add');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/formdata');
            $this->add(array(
    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
    'name' => 'option',
    'options' => array(
    'label' => 'Options Véhicule',
     'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class'   => 'Users\Entity\optionsvehicule',
                'property'       => 'property'
            ,   )));
```

the error message i received:
    No object manager was set.

Comment: is it being set by dependency injection?

Comment: @alex How could it have been the `__construct` calls the method `$this->getObjectManager()`, which could not have been set previously.

Comment: didn't see it in the constructor...that's why it was a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried and found similar error. After some search I found solution posted on https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues/175. Which works.

For implement you need to do some changes like that

In Module.php add method getFormElementConfig :

```
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'addForm' => 'Users\Form\addForm',
        ),
        'initializers' => array(
            'ObjectManagerInitializer' => function ($element, $formElements) {
                if ($element instanceof ObjectManagerAwareInterface) {
                    $services      = $formElements->getServiceLocator();
                    $entityManager = $services->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

                    $element->setObjectManager($entityManager);
                }
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

In Your Form Class addForm.php, replace constructor with init method  :

```
namespace Users\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
class addForm extends form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
    protected $objectManager;
    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    //public function __construct($name = null)
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/formdata');
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
            'name' => 'option',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Options Véhicule',
                'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class'   => 'Users\Entity\optionsvehicule',
                'property'       => 'property'
            ,   )));
```

In Your Controller Class, Call form obejct through Service Locator :

```
//$form = new addForm();
$forms = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager');
$form = $forms->get('addForm');
```

Comment: thank you, please why we add this line;                         'property'       => 'property' this got an error:                Property "property" could not be found in object "Vehicules\Entity\optionsvehicule"

Comment: Well actually this should be `property'       => 'propertyName'` where propertyName is field which shown with every checkbox. So it could be like  `property'       => 'username'`

Comment: Please i want do add ObjectSelect in the same form but i got this error: 

    Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Form\Element\ObjectSelect
!!

Answer (score 0):

The `$objectManager` property is undefined.

This is because you call the `$this->getObjectManager()` method immediately within the `__construct()` and before you set the variable.

The form *depends* on the object manager; so you could just add it as a constructor argument which would ensure it is set before the class is used.

Also, the constructor should only really be used for setting up the object's initial properties and state, use `init()` for modifying form elements.

```
class addForm extends Form
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('add-form');

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    // The form element manager will call `init()` 
    // on the form so we can add the elements in this method
    public function init() {
        //....
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/formdata');

        // $this->add(....
        // more elements added here
    }

}
```

Last thing is to register a factory that actually *does* the injection

```
class Module {

    public function getFormElementConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'ModuleName\Form\FooForm' => function($formElementManager) {
                    $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
                    $objectManager  = $serviceManager->get('ObjectManager'); 

                    $form = new Form\FooForm($objectManager); 

                    return $form;
                },
            ), 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i am really confused, i thought that all form's elements are added to the form due to the constructor with " $this->add(... " . i will post all my form to clarify things

Comment: thank you, i did all what you have said but i got an error:      Property "property" could not be found in object "Vehicules\Entity\optionsvehicule" !!